# Check if SoapClient exists

Tags: soap, exception, error-handling, try-catch, fatal-error

I'm battling with error detection in PHP...

I have a simple function which uses SoapClient to get bits of data from another one of my servers. The relevant parts are:

```
$options = array(
'uri' => 'https://www.php-web-host.com',
'location' => 'https://www.php-web-host.com/API/Country.php',
'trace' => 1);

$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);
$CountryCode = strtolower($client->GetCountryCode($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]));
```

The problem I'm having at the moment is that if the server I'm running this code on does not have SOAP installed, then I get a 500 server error (I haven't checked, but I'm guessing that the actual PHP problem is fatal exception?)

I've tried wrapping the above in try / catch blocks, but evidently it does not throw an exception. I've also tried set_error_handler, etc, but I can't "catch" this error.

The reason I need to catch it (as opposed to just installing SOAP) is that its for code that will be widely distributed, so I need to be able to somehow check for soap before connecting...

Any help is much appreciated...

John

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to solve my problem by using periklis example at [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error).

That example uses the register_shutdown_function which is called when the page is terminated (properly or due to an error).

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');

function shutdownFunction()
{

    $error = error_get_last();

    // check if this error was related to my code, if not, ignore it
if ( ($error['type'] == 1) && (strstr(strtolower($error['message']), 'soapclient') ) )
{

            print "<h1 style=\"color:red;\">ERROR!</h1>Your server does not appear to have SOAP installed. SOAP is required for this functionaliy";
    exit();
    } 

}
```

That seems to work for me... Happiness!